# How to download a child folder , if exists, for a given TFS project using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, dll, tfs

I am trying to download a folder child from a given TFS project.
All i have done so far is connecting to the server using a url https://.visualstudio.com ,  username, a password  and listing all the projects.
This is my code so far:

```
Add-Type -Path "$path1\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$path1\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$path1\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$path1\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$path1\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ProjectManagement.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$path2\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.dll"
$tfsurl = 'https://something.visualstudio.com'
$username = 'someuser@outlook.com'
$password = 'somepasswd'
$_tfs_server =[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($tfs_uri)

$cred = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)
$_tfs_server.Credentials = $cred
$_tfs_server.EnsureAuthenticated()

if($_tfs_server.HasAuthenticated){
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Connected to Team Foundation Server [" $tfs_uri "]"   
$tfsConfigurationServer = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConfigurationServerFactory]::GetConfigurationServer($tfs_uri)
$tpcService = $tfsConfigurationServer.GetService("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.ITeamProjectCollectionService")

$sortedCollection = $tpcService.GetCollections() | Sort-Object -Property Name
foreach($col in $sortedCollection){
    Write-Host $col.Name
}

$cssService = $_tfs_server.GetService("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.ICommonStructureService3")   

$sortedProjects = $cssService.ListAllProjects() | Sort-Object -Property Name 
Write-Host "Listing Projects"

foreach($project in $sortedProjects){
    Write-Host (" - " + $project.Name)
}

 } 
 else {
return;
 }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCXNQ.jpg

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, so you've connected, I assume this works? What have you tried so far to download a directory? What is the error you are encountering? SO is not a code writing service, we are here to assist you in your code, please edit and add what you have attempted.

Comment: Will is right, could you explain more detail about the error you encountered ? Did you mean you could now get the folder just not get the sub folders in the folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple code to get files from source control:

```
    $teamProjectCollection=new-object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection($tfsCollectionUrl,$cret)
    $teamProjectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated()
    $VersionControl = $teamProjectCollection.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer])
$workspace = $VersionControl.CreateWorkspace("BasicSccExamplePS", $VersionControl.AuthorizedUser);
    $workspace.Map("$/Agile2015/ClassLibrary2", "D:\\temp\\BasicSccExample")
    $workspace.Get()
```

To check whether folder/file exists, you can use GetItems() method:

```
$items=$VersionControl.GetItems("$/ScrumStarain/CustomCode/Properties2");
    Write-Output $items.Items.Count
    If($items.Items.Count -ne 0)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for not answering, i was able to make the script, but i have another problem. In my computer it runs fine, but in another laptop it fails at EnsureAuthenticated(). I mention that i have included all the necessary .dll files

Comment: @GeriLali What's the value of $path1? Are there errors in the Output window when add these assemblies? I am using C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer